# Change the value in a view on keeping a button pressed

Tags: android, view

Framework: **Android**

I have a `TextView` where I would like to change the text on keeping an `ImageView` pressed.

Note: I am not referring to changing the text on clicking the view, but on *pressing* the view and on the amount of *time* that it is pressed.

e.g. I press the image and the text becomes `2`. Keep it pressed for another half a second and the text becomes `3`.

I haven't found a similar question yet, yet if you have, please redirect me. Thank you.

Comment: Currently I am using a `CountDownTimer` object to count 500 ms and then update my text value on the `ACTION_DOWN` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of `OnTouchListener` and run your number changing algorithm in `ACTION_DOWN`

Comment: Thanks. I used a `Handler` for every 500ms on the `ACTION_DOWN` touch.

Comment: Glad that worked @AnindyaDutta..  To make answers helpful to others as well, give a thought on upvoting and accepting the answers that helped you.

Comment: Did that. I am pretty new to Stack Overflow, thank you for telling how things work around here.